# Дизассемблирование машинных методов не поддерживается

Tags: c#, .net, компиляция

Поиграл с флагами атрибута `MethodImpl`, и решил поставить туда вторым параметром `MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Native`, после чего увидел в `ildasm` следующее:

```
.method public hidebysig static !!T  Read<valuetype .ctor (class [mscorlib]System.ValueType modreq([mscorlib]System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType)) T>(class [mscorlib]System.IO.Stream 'stream',
                                                                                                                                                               uint64& read) native managed aggressiveinlining
{
  .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
  .param type T 
  .custom instance void System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsUnmanagedAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
  // Дизассемблирование машинных методов не поддерживается.
  //  Managed TargetRVA = 0x0000219C
} // end of method StreamExtensions::Read
```

Можно ли предположить что это некая оптимизация, которая позволит коду выполняться быстрее?

Comment: Хотя... После запуска: `"Собственный управляемый код в настоящее время не поддерживается."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, это нельзя считать "просто оптимизацией". Сама возможность поставить этот флаг на метод - некритичный баг компилятора.

"Нативный метод" - это метод, скомпилированный в машинный код вместо MSIL. Написать нативный метод на C# нельзя, его надо писать на другом языке и статически линковать. Или писать на C++/CLI, где компилятор поддерживает оба режима.

Побочный эффект существования таких методов - сборка перестаёт быть AnyCPU-сборкой, а также не может быть использована в песочнице.